# Is there a way to write a single expression over multiple lines in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, haml

I have this in one of my haml views:

```
-form_for :news_item_comment, :url=>{:id => comment.id, :controller => 'comment' , :action => 'add_comment'}, :html => {:id => "form-#{comment.id}"}  do |f|    
   ...
```

Since it's really long and hard to read I want to split it over 2 lines. Is there anyway to do this without violating haml's whitespace rules?

Comment: I have a similar case: `= link_to image_tag( product.product_images.find_by_scene_id( @scene ).product_image.url(:small), :alt => to_slug(product.name) ), '#'`. I think this question might be of general use, so I'll start a little bounty.

Comment: Why don't you just set the number of columns in your texteditor to a reasonable size that fits your screen?

Comment: Because then I'd still have a very long line. I want this code to get more readable, very long lines are still hard to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is [multiline syntax](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/HAML_REFERENCE.md.html#multiline). However, it's encouraged that you move your long lines into helper methods rather than use it, as that will make your templates more readable in the long run.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Helper methods are preferred to multi-line HAML. If you *need* multiple lines, you're doing way too much in your view.

Comment: I hope anyone with this problem will run into this post, because that's a pretty fundamentally different, and probably much better way to solve the issue of readability I wanted to adress.

Comment: Seems that the link has expired - 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of haml there was no way to multi-line a single statement - something which I was frustrated with in the same way you are as it made templates way harder to read in some cases.

In theory there is a multi-line [syntax](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/HAML_CHANGELOG.md.html#multiline) for handling statements with lots of attributes.  I have not tried to use it - but it's worth a shot, if that doesn't work then it is likely still the case that you cannot multi-line that type of statement.

Comment: Seems that the link has expired - 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

The '|' can be used as a line separator for multi line syntax.Refer this http://www.mail-archive.com/haml@googlegroups.com/msg04722.html